# Memory space occupied by an array

Tags: c, arrays, memory

This is a basic question, but I couldn't find a definitive answer. Hope someone can shed some light.

I want to know how much memory space does one array occupy.

Do multiple arrays of different types but with the same combined  byte size occupy the same amount of memory?

Does an array occupy the same memory space as multiple arrays with the same size combined?

Some examples:

(on my system 8051 microcontroller, 
      `char = 1 byte;` 
      `int = 2 bytes ;` 
      `float = 4 bytes;`)

```
//case 1
char array_nr1[40];

//case 2
char array_nr1[10];
char array_nr2[10]; 
char array_nr3[10]; 
char array_nr4[10]; 

//case 3 
int array_nr1[10];
int array_nr2[10]; 

//case 4
float array_nr1[10];

//case 5 
char array_nr1[10];
int array_nr2[5];
float array_nr3[5];
```

Do all 5 cases take the same amount of memory (40 bytes)? Is there any other data that is stored on a memory (ex. the array base address)

Thank you.

Comment: Without any `padding`, `optimization` and `packing`, theoritically, yes.

Comment: What does it mean for "a case" to "take memory"? Each object requires memory if it has storage, but whether any memory is required for that depends on what you do. If the object is never referred to, the compiler may choose not to allocate any storage for it. The only sensible thing you can ask about is the *size* of each object.

Comment: are you sure you were calculting that correctly? int usually takes 4 byte of space, so two arrays of each 10 int would take 80 byte, not 40

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `sizeof(int)` is not necessarily 4 bytes on all platforms.

Comment: @barakmanos i was referring to `char = 1 byte ; int = 2 bytes ; float = 4 bytes` supplied by OP.

Comment: On my system int is on 2 bytes.

Comment: Depends. Some ABI's might require extra alignment for `type[NUMBER]` beyond the alignment of `type`. In that case, multiple arrays *might* take more space than a single continuous one.

Answer (score 5):

Memory occupied by an array can be gotten by using sizeof operator. For example

```
char array_nr1[40];

printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( array_nr1 ) );
```

The output will be 40 because `sizeof( char )` that is size of the element of the array is guaranteed to be equal to 1

You could write the same for example for array

```
int array_nr1[10];
```

But it would be better to calculate the size of array by multiplying sizeof of its element by the numkber of elements.

So this record

```
sizeof( array_nr1 )
```

is equivalent to

```
10 * sizeof( int )
```

So the question is what is the size of an object of type int? It depends on the implementation. For example sizeof( int ) can be equal to 2 or to 4 or to some other value.

So in your case if `sizeof( int )` is equal to 2 then these two arrays

```
int array_nr1[10];
int array_nr2[10];
```

occupy `2 * ( 10 * sizeof( int ) )` => 40 bytes. It is  the same memory volume that is occupied by array

```
char array_nr1[40];
```

If `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4 then the arrays occupy different amounts of memory.

The same observation is valid for arrays of type float. Usually the size in bytes of an object of type float is equal to 4. So if `sizeof( int )` is equal to 2 then these arrays

```
char array_nr1[10];
int array_nr2[5];
float array_nr3[5];
```

occuoy the same amount of memory as array

```
char array_nr1[40];
```

because

10 * sizeof( char ) + 5 * sizeof( int ) + 5 * sizeof( float ) => 10 * 1 + 5 * 2 + 5 * 4 => 40 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

from C how to program p.297

> To calculate the amount of memory used by an array, multiply the number of elements
> by the size in bytes each element occupies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).